# Files changes listening doesn't work (changes are not shown) on Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, liveserver

I joined the project on Nuxt v2.15.4 and Vue v2.6.12.

After "yarn dev" project is starting on localhost:3000, but changes listening doens't work (any changes in *.vue, *.scss are not shown). To see changes it needs to make "yarn dev" once again.

VSCode, Windows 11

nuxt.config.js is here:

```
 export default {
 generate: {
 fallback: true
   },
 publicRuntimeConfig: {
 baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/'
   },
 router: {
 base: process.env.BASE_URL || '/',
 linkActiveClass: 'active',
 linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
 middleware: ['saveUtmTags']
   },
 
   /*
 Global CSS
 */
 css: [{ src: '~assets/scss/app.scss', lang: 'scss' }],
   /*
 Plugins to load before mounting the App
 */
 plugins: [
 src: '~/plugins/i18n' },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vuelidate'
     },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vue-lightbox',
 ssr: false
     },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vue-lazysizes.client',
 ssr: false
     },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vue-youtube-embed',
 ssr: false
     },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vue2-smooth-scroll',
 ssr: false
     },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/vue-flickity',
 ssr: false
     },
 src: '~/plugins/common-components' },
     {
 src: '~/plugins/gtm',
 ssr: false
     }
   ],
   /*
 Nuxt.js dev-modules
 */
 buildModules: [
 Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
     '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
 [
       '@nuxtjs/moment',
       {
 defaultLocale: 'en',
 locales: ['ru', 'zh-cn', 'th']
       }
     ]
   ],
   /*
 Nuxt.js modules
 */
 modules: [
 [
       '@nuxtjs/robots',
       {
 UserAgent: '*',
 Disallow: ['/?=*', '/*utm=*'],
 Sitemap: ''
       }
     ],
     'cookie-universal-nuxt',
     '@nuxtjs/moment',
 [
       '@nuxtjs/gtm',
       {
 scriptDefer: true
       }
     ],
 [
       '@nuxtjs/google-gtag',
       {
 id: 'UA-185349291-1'
       }
     ],
 [
       'nuxt-facebook-pixel-module',
       {
 pixelId: '444888023551083',
 autoPageView: true
       }
     ],
 [
       '@aceforth/nuxt-optimized-images',
       {
 mozjpeg: {
 quality: 80,
 maxMemory: 65536 // 64Mb
         },
 svgo: { plugins: [{ name: 'removeViewBox', active: false }] }
       }
     ],
     '@nuxtjs/axios',
     'nuxt-compress',
 [
       'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
       {
 componentPlugins: [
           'DropdownPlugin',
           'CollapsePlugin',
           'ModalPlugin',
           'CarouselPlugin',
           'TabsPlugin',
           'TooltipPlugin',
           'VBVisiblePlugin'
         ]
       }
     ],
 [
       'nuxt-i18n',
       {
 baseUrl: '',
 locales: [
           {
 code: 'ru',
 iso: 'ru',
 file: 'ru.json',
 name: 'RU'
           },
           {
 code: 'en',
 iso: 'en',
 file: 'en.json',
 name: 'EN'
           },
           {
 code: 'zh',
 iso: 'zh',
 file: 'zh.json',
 name: 'ZH'
           },
           {
 code: 'th',
 iso: 'th',
 file: 'th.json',
 name: 'TH'
           }
         ],
 lazy: true,
 langDir: 'lang/',
 defaultLocale: 'en',
 detectBrowserLanguage: false,
 vueI18n: {
 numberFormats: {
 ru: {
 locales: 'ru-RU',
 currency: {
 style: 'currency',
 currency: 'usd',
 maximumFractionDigits: 0,
 minimumFractionDigits: 0
               }
             },
 en: {
 locales: 'en-US',
 currency: {
 style: 'currency',
 currency: 'usd',
 maximumFractionDigits: 0,
 minimumFractionDigits: 0
               }
             },
 zh: {
 locales: 'zh-CN',
 currency: {
 style: 'currency',
 currency: 'usd',
 maximumFractionDigits: 0,
 minimumFractionDigits: 0
               }
             },
 th: {
 locales: 'th-TH',
 currency: {
 style: 'currency',
 currency: 'thb',
 maximumFractionDigits: 0,
 minimumFractionDigits: 0
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     ],
 [
       '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
       {
 hostname: '',
 defaults: {
 priority: 1,
 lastmod: new Date()
         }
       }
     ]
   ],
   /*
 Axios module configuration
 See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
 */
 axios: {
 baseURL: process.env.API_URL || API_URL,
 proxy: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
 prefix: '/api/'
   },
 proxy: {
     '/api/': { target: API_URL, pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' } }
   },
   /*
 Build configuration
 */
 build: {
     /*
 You can extend webpack config here
 */
 extend(config, { isDev, isClient, loaders: { vue } }) {
 vue.transformAssetUrls.img = ['data-src', 'src']
 vue.transformAssetUrls.source = ['data-srcset', 'srcset']
     }
   }
 target: 'static'
}
```

Already tried to manually add "poll: true" in my config, but nothing happened.

Don't have any significant errors at console.

Have you any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks.